# Create a variable inside another statement

Tags: c++

Is there a way to allocate a variable within the scope of a parameter list? By using `new` we can do the following :

```
Class A{ /*... snip ...*/ };

void myFunc(A* a){ }

int main(...){
    myFunc(new A());
    return 0;
}
```

This will create a new A. What if the signature of myFunc was

```
void myFunc(A a);
```

instead. Is there a syntax to create local instance inside the `myFunc()` parameter list? I'm looking for something like

```
myFunc(A());
```

or

```
myFunc(A a());
```

Another use would be for something like :

```
A a(123);
if(a == A(123)){ }
```

The net effect is to save one line, but it also creates a scope within the parameters list which makes me wonder if it is allowed at all.

Comment: arguments are pushed on the stack when a function is called, I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: I want to create a variable within the scope of the parameters without using new

Comment: @Eric Do you mean a _vaiable_ or a temporary rvalue actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create a variable to pass to the function you can use a [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) / [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class A{ /*... snip ...*/ };

void myFunc(A a){ }

int main(){
    myFunc(A{});
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7699f394894746ac)

You can also use this with classes that have constructors that take multiple parameters

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class A
{ 
private:
    int foo;
    int bar;
    double foobar;
public:
    A(int a, int b, double c) : foo(a), bar(b), foobar(c) {}

};

void myFunc(A a){ }

int main(){
    myFunc(A{1,2,3.0});
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e8ade93450a7fff)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for. In my example the default constructor for A is used, but can I use this syntax with more complex objects or other constructors?

Comment: Ok this does compile an run properly, but this goes against the definition of "aggregate" from the link you posted

Comment: @Eric Updated to add reference to list initialization.

Answer (score 1):

C++ supports this with the `myFunc(A());` syntax you posed in your question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char lazybuff[500];

class Point
{
  public:
    Point (double x, double y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) { }
    char * ToString (void) { sprintf (lazybuff, "%f, %f", m_x, m_y); return lazybuff; }

  private:
    double m_x, m_y;
};

void print_point (Point print_me)
{
  printf ("%s\n", print_me.ToString());
}

int main (void)
{
  print_point (Point(5, 3));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *epic facepalm. Ok, I should get some sleep, thanks